# How to pass a List<CustomClass> from ASP.NET to Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I plan to use silverlight for drawing a figure (network chart). For this I need a `List` of `CustomClass` that is generated by ASP.NET (using data fetched from SqlServer). How to pass a `List<CustomClass>` to Silverlight?

EDIT: Is there any option other than using a webservice middleware? I just need to pass an object during the silverlight startup. The silverlight chart is static. Does it really need webservices?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need and how your enviroment is, you can store the data in the `Session` object and access them in silverlight.

or

You can create a Webservice and call them from silverlight. 
The Webservice gets the data from you Sql Server and gave them back to silverlight.

**More information about access sessions:**

[Access Sessions from Silverlight and ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightASPNetSessions.aspx)

**More information about WCF**

[YoutTube - Connecting Silverlight to WCF](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8YCFufS2Qk)

[Codeplex - 4 Simple Steps to Consume WCF Service using Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/4StepsSilverLight.aspx)

[How To: Create a “Hello World” WCF Service Using Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2007/10/15/how-to-create-a-hello-world-wcf-service-using-visual-studio.aspx)

**hope this helps**

Comment: Well, I just need to pass an object during the silverlight startup. Does it really need webservices?

Comment: @neutrino: No. It is not ASP.NET which starts the silverlight application. It's the user's web browser. And the web browser does not know anything about `List` or `CustomClass`. Thus, the silverlight application must retrieve the List on its own. And a web service is a common way to do so. And it's actually not hard.

Comment: @neutrino i updated my answer. Maybe you can use the session object to store the data, i dont know you enviroment and session handling.

Comment: Could you pls comment on the strategy of answer I added.

Comment: @dknaack I was referring to http://www.dotnetglobe.com/2011/07/passing-objects-between-aspnet-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen WCF RIA Services? see a simple tutorial here http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-1-Getting-Started.aspx. It makes what you want to achieve very easy. Otherwise you could use plain old WCF.

Comment: Can't I directly pass the List<> as, say an argument?

Comment: You need to remember that Silverlight is running on the client's machine. The only way to talk to it is via web services or javascript (you could hack passing the list from asp.net to javascript... but lets not go there its a really bad option). Just invest some time with RIA its really very easy.

Answer (score 0):

WCF RIA services is a Microsoft Technology, which meets your requirements:

- It creates a Web Service, which is able to expose the Business Objects from the Database to the Silverlight client
- It generates client code to access the Business Objects in Silverlight

See a basic walkthrough [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707376%28v=vs.91%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I found out [this](http://www.dotnetglobe.com/2011/07/passing-objects-between-aspnet-and.html). Looks like a hack, bit this is the thing I was looking for. Please comment on this strategy.